# Hilbert style axiom system without generalisation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, proof-theory, hilbert-calculus

I the book *Computational Complexity* by C. Papadimitriou he introduces for first order logic the following axioms:

> **AX0**: Any expression whose Boolean form is a tautology.
>
> **AX1**: Any expression of the following form:
>
> **AX1a**: $t = t$.
>
> **AX1b**: $(t_1 = t_1' \land \ldots \land t_k = t_k') \Rightarrow f(t_1, \ldots, t_k) = f(t_1', \ldots, t_k')$.
>
> **AX1c**: $(t_1 = t_1' \land \ldots \land t_k = t_k') \Rightarrow (R(t_1,\ldots,t_k) \Rightarrow R(t_1', \ldots, t_k'))$.
>
> **AX2**: Any expression of the form $\forall x \phi \Rightarrow \phi[x \leftarrow t]$
>
> **AX3**: Any expression of the form $\phi \Rightarrow \forall \phi$, with $x$ not free in $\phi$.
>
> **AX4**: Any expression of the form $(\forall x(\phi \Rightarrow \varphi)) \Rightarrow (\forall x \phi \Rightarrow \forall x \varphi)$.

Remerk: **AX0** includes Modus Ponens. And $t$ denotes a term in the language of first order logic.

In the text there is a form of generalisation mentioned, to cite the text (the paragraph's where all these axioms are justified):

> **Proposition 5.7**: If $\phi$ is valid, then so is $\forall x \phi$.
>
> There is a stronger form of this. Suppose that $x$ does not occur free in $\phi$. Then we claim that $\phi \Rightarrow \forall x \phi$ is valid. The reason is that, any model that satisfies $\phi$ will also satisfy $\forall x\phi$, as the $x = u$ part of the definition of satisfaction becomes irrelevant. We summarize this as follows:
>
> **Proposition 5.8.**: If $x$ does not appear free in $\phi$, then $\phi \Rightarrow \forall \phi$ is valid.

What makes me wonder is that Propostion 5.7 is entirely dropped from the axioms, so I thought it might be deducable from the the other. And indeed if $x$ does no appear free in $\phi$, then Modus ponus with **AX3** gives it, but what if $x$ does appear free in $\phi$. Surely by definition, if then $\phi$ is valid it must be satisfied by every model, in particular whatever value the free variable has, which makes this rule evident. But in that case I do not see how to deduce it from the other axioms...

> So, why is the rule of generalisation missing in the axioms? Is it somehow deducible from the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a quite common presentation of first-order logic.

See e.g.:

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA112), Academic Press (2nd ed. 2001), page 109-on.

It has one *rule of inference* only : *modus ponens*, while [Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) is derivable in the form [see [page 117](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA117)]:

> If $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $x$ do not occur free in any formula in $\Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash ∀x \ \varphi$.

The proof is by induction on the lenght of the *derivation* of $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ (and it needs axioms Ax3 and Ax4).

With $\Gamma = \emptyset$, we have : if $\vdash \varphi$, then $\vdash \forall x \ \varphi$.